# Ionic plugins not installed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an issue only with android build, when I running on emulator or device android I get the error that ALL plugins are not installed, on ios emulator or device I dont have this issue

Any idea?

Thanks
Evripides

Comment: Share your cordova, ionic versions and plugins you added.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your plugins are not prepared.

Try `cordova prepare` then `npm install` and finally `ionic cordova platform add <your_platform>`

Your problem is specific with android so your platform should be `android`

Comment: still the same, on ios no problem at all

Comment: try ```ionic cordova platform rm android``` then ```ionic cordova platform add android```

Answer (score 0):

remove `node module` and `package.json.lock` file manually

remove `android platform` using command `ionic cordova platform rm android`

```
npm i

ionic cordova platform add android
```

and install all plugins like below

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file --save
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes android build fails dependencies mismatch so and re run fresh.

delete `node_module`

```
npm i
ionic cordova rm android 
ionic cordova add platform android
```

Comment: Why should he do that?

Comment: bcz in ionic build somtime skips dependencis and currupt dependencis starting fress is good bcz we have all dependencies in package.json.if it wrong pls correct me

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found the error on 1 plugin in-app-purchase, I removed it and reinstall it and now all are fine

Thank you all